# Onedrive could not be reinstalled in windows7 pc 32bit- error code 0x80040c97

Tags: windows-7, onedrive, 32-bit

I have and 32 bit pc in which installed windows7. Earlier I use onedrive on it. But due to some reason I have to format my PC. So when I tried to reinstall Onedrive on it, it  could not be reinstalled in windows7 pc 32bit. and it shows error code 0x80040c97

[image]

Comment: Did you download a fresh copy and try again?. Is the date and time correct on your PC?

Comment: Yes, I dowloaded fresh onedrive and also time date correct, same problem I faced earlier in another pc,  But few days after   hard drive corrupted, i changed hard drive n again able to install onedrive, but here after formating pc and reinstalling onedrive, it couldnot be installed n shwing error.

Comment: are All the Windows updates installed since you re-installed Windows 7?

Comment: Yes windows7 sp1 installed

Comment: There are well over 100 updates after SP1, did you install these using Windows updates in control panel? Run windows updates over and over until it offers no more updates.

Comment: Yes yes, i installed using windows updates

Comment: Have a look over here>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=0x80040c97&tab=&status=all&advFil=&IsSuggestedTerm=false&isFilterExpanded=undefined&CurrentScope.ForumName=&CurrentScope.Filter=&ContentTypeScope=&page=1&sort=Relevance&dir=Desc

Comment: I just downloaded this one drive installer and it installed fine on my W7 PC>>>>https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=248256

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Even after trying searching everything in the microsoft forum, my issues on reinstallation of onedrive in windows7 32bit, failed and also found many more are facing the same problem without any solution in the microsoft forum. Still waiting for solution.

Comment: I find a similar [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-couldnt-be-installed-error-0x80040c97/9484132d-0b58-420f-a72d-8e0d30b64ff9?page=1), some users said they installed an older version successfully. 
It's best to refer to replies from *NhatQuangHo* and *chitinhVukhuc*.

Comment: @Emily I had 2013 version of onedrive in my hardrive, even if I m able to install this, aftwrwards it couldnot be linkef with hotmail account and it says download latest version of onedrive. After downloading latest version, above problem recurs.

Comment: Thanks @moab after reinstallation of windows7 on 25.05.2020, even  after multiple try  onedrive could not installed in my pc. But as per your above advice, my windows update was running and daily my windows 7 updates some files,  Today on 28.05.2020, I am able to install Onedrive on my PC. Thanks again